# How to fix the broken characters in terminal inside docker container?

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnome-terminal, docker

I'm running shell script inside a docker container based on ubuntu base image but I'm getting ���� in the terminal output instead of something like this ..

```
printf "${G}==> ${BL}Checking device booting up status .. ${G}<==${NC}""\n"

 ==> Checking device booting up status ����.. <==
Android-Service    | ==> adb: device offline ���� <==
```

so do I need to install a specific library for fonts ?

Comment: Please be more specific about *"some shell script"*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the question boxes displayed in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367082/whats-the-question-boxes-displayed-in-the-terminal)